# Mysql statement to select names that start with specific range of characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm writing the following statement to select names that starts with a range of characters.

```
select name from db.table where name like '[c-e]%';
```

The statement does not return anything to me. But when I change it to:

```
select name from db.table where name like 'c%';
```

It returns records.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Are you using a case or accent sensitive collation?

Comment: I have no clue about what you are asking. But I haven't specified this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@juergen d is right but a little change required as you want to check all the name starting from in range [c-d] so

```
select name from db.table where name REGEXP '^[c-e].+';
```

"^" indicates that match when starting must match range [c-e]

Answer (score 3):

instead of `LIKE` use `REGEXP`

```
select name from db.table where name REGEXP '[c-e].+';
```

See [MySQL Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `REGEXP` as:

```
SELECT name FROM db.table where name REGEXP '[c-e].+';
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you could use `REGEXP`; but when you want a *range* of starting characters, you can also do:

```
SELECT name FROM db.table WHERE name >= 'c' AND name < 'f';
```

This could be faster, as it can take advantage of an index in the `name` field to avoid a full scan.